# Form Cloning using Jquery with increment form fields name

Tags: jquery, forms, clone

My form has two fields are short description and long description initially the form fileds names are **section[new][1][description]** and **section[new][1][ldescription]**

I would like to generate clone form fields which generate names like **section[new][2][description]** and **section[new][2][ldescription]**.
each time i clone new form it should generate form fields names with increment id in between like **section[new][incrementid goes here][description]**

How to achieve this using regex or any other jquery techniques?

Here is code i'm using for form clonning

```
jQuery("button.add").on("click", clone); 

function clone(){
var clone = jQuery(this).parents(".pbone_section_default").clone()
    .appendTo("#section_list")
    .attr("id", "pbone_section_default_" +  cloneIndex)
    .find("*")
    .each(function() {
        // here we can put any logic to achieve desire element name  
        this.name = logic goes here;
    })
    .on('click','button.delete',remove);
};
```

Comment: What's in your variable `cloneIndex` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.match()` and `.replace()` to find the number in the string an increment it:

```
.each(function() {
    this.name = incrementNumberinString(this.name);
});

var incrementNumberinString = function (string){
  var i = parseInt(string.match(/\d{1}/g))+1;
  return string.replace(/\d{1}/g, i)
}
```

The regex will find any digit which is existing exactly 1 times.

See [here](https://regex101.com/r/xY1pF6/1) for an example of the Regex.

Note: This will only work under the assumption that there is only 1 number inside your inputs name.

[Working Example](https://jsfiddle.net/7oy293qx/)

Comment: This is a brilliant solution. Solved a problem I have been having for a while.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it can be done (you were close).. Assuming you are using a **0 based indexing** (i.e. starting from `section[new][0][description]`), try this code:

```
function clone(){
    var $clone = $(".pbone_section_default").last(),
        index = $clone.index();

    $clone.clone()
          .appendTo("#section_list")
          .find("[name*='["+index+"]']")
          .each(function(){
            $(this).attr("name", $(this).attr("name").replace("["+ index +"]", "["+ parseInt(index+1) +"]"));
          });
};
```

see a working example here: [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/kfmcg334/)

Anyway, i suggest you to use templating engine instead, like [Mustache](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js) or [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/).. but there are plenty of them.. check [this article](http://www.creativebloq.com/web-design/templating-engines-9134396) and see which suits better to your projet

Comment: If you can be sure that the number in the name is always equal the elements index in the dom, than this will be OK, otherwise this could lead to an unexpected behaviour.

Comment: @empiric sure, that's not bulletproof! There are better ways to do that, like templating as i suggested.. anyway i wanted to pursue what user was trying to do

Comment: @pumpkinzzz can you please tell me what are the benefits of using templating engine?